# I need help combining update statements into 1 statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I need to update around 500 records with the same `set` values but different `where` values in SQL (Oracle).  I want to execute as one statement instead of 500 different statements. Any help is appreciated. Below is an example my update statements.

```
update proddta.f564211 
  set sd$prdcflg = '' 
where sd$prcflg = 'Y' 
AND sddoco = 86615 
and sddcto = 'S1' 
and sdlnid = 1.000

update proddta.f564211 
  set sd$prdcflg = '' 
where sd$prcflg = 'Y' 
AND sddoco = 86615 
and sddcto = 'S1' 
and sdlnid = 2.100

update proddta.f564211 
  set sd$prdcflg = '' 
where sd$prcflg = 'Y' 
AND sddoco = 86618 
and sddcto = 'S1' 
and sdlnid = 1.000

update proddta.f564211 
  set sd$prdcflg = '' 
where sd$prcflg = 'Y' 
AND sddoco = 86618 
and sddcto = 'S1' 
and sdlnid = 2.100
```

Comment: data you are using in where condition are from some table?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
update proddta.f564211
set    sd$prdcflg = null
where  sd$prcflg = 'Y'
and    sddcto = 'S1'
and    ( sddoco, sdlnid ) in 
       ( (86615, 1.000)
       , (86615, 2.100)
       , (86618, 1.000)
       , (86618, 2.100) );
```